# Alignemnt issue with the warning popup in election page

Tags: bug, design, election, voting

During the [election](https://photo.stackexchange.com/election?cb=1), if any user less than 150 reputation trying to vote in the final phase, we are receiving the following warning in the popup.

> You need at least 150 reputation to vote

The warning popup is displaying near the user details, few users entered lot of details in the section, for them it looks like the warning box is displaying far away.

GIF for the same.

[image: Trying to vote in the final phase]

Can this warning popup to be display near the Choices button.